# mtpfs error, tried everything it seems

Tags: usb, android, samsung

Attempting to connect to my Samsung Galaxy S4 using mtpfs as many guides tell me to do results in this:

```
leaves@sakamoto:~$ mtpfs
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 0
Attempting to connect device
libusb_open() failed!: No such file or directory
LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
Unable to open raw device 0
```

I have no clue what to do any more, I've tried using jmtpfs, nothing seems to work. For now I'm using ftp to move files around, but I'd like to be able to use USB as it's faster.

Comment: can you make a q/a on askubuntu, asking how to use ftp with android, and then give your answer?